# Implement openweathermap exaplme code

Tags: javascript, api, openweathermap

i do not know if anybody of u have used the OpenWeatherMap API.

I need help to implement the following map into my website: http://www.openweathermap.com/city/732770

Unfortunately i was unable to find any good documentation how to do that. I also have written to the support, but they cannot help me, which is more than strange. 
I will be very thankful, if anybody has achieved that and can share some code !

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use JavaScript for almost anything you want to do with OWM. Mostly what they do is provide the raw data in various formats such as XML or JSON what you can then include in your JavaScript (or I suppose PHP) applications.

Also you will need to register for an API key. You basically can't do anything without one.

Comment: Hi Showcaselfloyd, i have already an account and i am getting some weather information. My problem is how to implement the map on my website ?

Comment: Like I said you will most likely need to use JavaScript to parse the Data into a usable format first. What language is your application written in?